# Issue in submitting - update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Thanks for the input so far.
The logic is there but it still does not want to submit when passing true to submit...
I added an alert to see if it gets called when value is true, but for some strange reason, the 'return false' is not passing value to submit....

I cant understand what the issue is. Starting to get intimidated lol

```
    <form name="newuser" id="form" method="post" action="do_new_user.php" onSubmit="return validateForm(false)"> 


    function validateForm(submitNow){


if (submitNow == true){
         alert ('call ok');
     return true;
     }

else
{
    var x=document.forms["newuser"]["name"].value;
    var x2=document.forms["newuser"]["surname"].value;
    var x3=document.forms["newuser"]["email"].value;
    var x4=document.forms["newuser"]["password1"].value;
    var x5=document.forms["newuser"]["password2"].value;

    if (x==null || x=="") 
      {

      $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#form_status").text("Please enter your name.");
      return false;
      }

    if (x2==null || x2=="") 
      {
      $("#form_status p").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#form_status").text("Please enter your surname.");
      return false;
      }

    if (x3==null || x3=="") 
      {
      $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#form_status").text("Please enter your email address.");
      return false;
      } 

    var atpos=x3.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x3.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x3.length)
      {
      $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#form_status").text("Email address in invalid.");
      return false;
      }

    if (x4==null || x4=="") 
      {
      $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#form_status").text("Please enter your password.");
      return false;
      }   

    if (x5==null || x5=="") 
      {
      $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#form_status").text("Please re-enter your password.");
      return false;
      } 

    if (x4!==x5)
      {
      $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
      $("#form_status").text("Password Mismatch.");
      return false; 
      }

    //Check if username exists.
    $.post("http://ryangosden.com/breadcrumbs/check_user_exists.php",  
             {
                x3 : x3
             } , 

             function(data)
              { 

                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                if (obj.email_exists == 1) 
                  {   
                    $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#form_status").text("Email Address Taken.");

                }  

                if (obj.email_exists == 2)   
                  {   
                $("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#form_status").text("Email ok.");
                    validateForm(true);
                  }  
    });
     return false; 
}


}
```

Comment: This has stumped me.... still does not submit when all values are true....any one have any ideas where the issue is? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the form should submit when email is not taken (and all other fields OK)

Which seem to be done at this point of your code :

```
$("#form_status").fadeIn("slow");
     $("#form_status").text("Email ok.");
     validateForm(true);
}
```

You have to catch the argument so you can submit the form, which could be done at the beginning of your function :

```
function validateForm(submitNow) {

   if (submitNow) return true;

   [... rest of function...]
}
```

Thanks to A. Wolff and Karl-André Gagnon for their comments, my first answer was too quick :)

**Update:**

Here is a working example you can extend on

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function validateform(submitNow) {
    if (submitNow) return true;
    else if ($('#input').val()) return validateform(true);
    alert('Please enter a value');
    return false;
}
</script>
<form id="#form" action="http://google.com" onsubmit="javascript:return validateform()">
    <input type="text" id="input"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: this will call submit method recursively

Comment: true... so it has to catch the argument... i'll edit my answer

Comment: Return in post call won't submit the form.

Comment: @OP there is a huge security probleme here, you'll need a PHP validation since users can change value during the post call, but i'm sure you knew it.

Comment: +1 Karl-Andre, or at least, double-check the data after the submission to reject if user forced the form (which is easy)

Comment: Hi all, Yes thank you Karl, as Panadaiolo suggested, ive added a secondary php check after js validation passes. Prbelm is... i still cant get form to submit even when adding suggested code...

Comment: I added a working example so you might compare with your version to find what's wrong with it